# Javascript print triangle doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript

I have to print a triangle formed of '#'.

This is my code:

```
function show(n){
  var text ="";
for(var i=1;i<=n;i++){
    for(var j=1;j<=i;j++){
        text+='#';

      }
     console.log(text);
    }

}
show(4);
```

For this input I get:

```
#
###
######
##########
```

But I want to get:

```
#
##
###
####
```

What is wrong in my code? Thanks

Comment: You do not reset `text` inside the loop. So each line will be appended to the last one.

Comment: As an option, you can use `for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    console.log('#'.repeat(i));
}`.

Comment: @Tushar Very informative, Indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Try to clear your `text` in the outer for loop,

```
for(var i=1;i<=n;i++){
    text = "";
```

Full code would be,

```
function show(n){
 var text;
 for(var i=1;i<=n;i++){
    text = "";
    for(var j=1;j<=i;j++){
        text+='#';
    }
    console.log(text);
 }
}
show(4);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need two loops for that. Just append one character in each iteration and print it out:

```
var text = "";

for(var i=0; i < n; i++){ 
 text += "#";
 console.log(text); 
}

//prints for n=8: 

#
##
###
####
#####
######
#######
########
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do loop this way:

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
function show(n){
    var text = "";
    for(var i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(var j=1;j<=i;j++){
          text+='#';
        }
        text+="<br/>";
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = text;
    }
}
show(4);
</script>
```

[Your Output](https://jsfiddle.net/wjatxd2w/1/)